# Writing a tf broadcaster (Python)

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't really understand this tutorial. Link to the tutorial :- [Click here](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20broadcaster%20%28Python%29)

I can understand how broadcaster code works but the launch code seems too strange.

```
    <node name="turtle1_tf_broadcaster" pkg="learning_tf" type="turtle_tf_broadcaster.py" respawn="false" output="screen" >
  <param name="turtle" type="string" value="turtle1" />
</node>
<node name="turtle2_tf_broadcaster" pkg="learning_tf" type="turtle_tf_broadcaster.py" respawn="false" output="screen" >
  <param name="turtle" type="string" value="turtle2" /> 
</node>
```

To my understanding, the above code creates two instances of the node right? So we should have turtle1 and turtle2 right?

But they mentioned,

"If you run tf_echo for the transform between the world and turtle 2, you should not see a transform, because the second turtle is not there yet."

I really don't understand how this works. Please explain.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/378167/writing-a-tf-broadcaster-(python)/) by [Chan](https://answers.ros.org/users/56593/chan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2021-05-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2021-05-12**:
What tutorial? Can you please update your question to a link to the tutorial?

**Comment by [Chan](https://answers.ros.org/users/56593/chan/) on 2021-05-12**:
Updated the question with link. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The above code creates 2 instances of the `turtle_tf_brodcaster.py` node.

By running `rosnode list`, you would find the two `nodes`, named as `turtle1_tf_broadcaster` and `turtle2_tf_broadcaster` respectively.

We are pasing the values of the `param` named `turtle` to the two `nodes`. For the first node, we are setting the value of the `turtle` `param` to `turtle1`, and for the second node, we are setting it to `turtle2`.

Each node is responsible for finding the value of `world -> turtleX` transform and then printing it.

`world -> turtle1` transform exists because of the following lines present in the `launch` file -

```
<node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node" name="sim"/>
<node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtle_teleop_key" name="teleop" output="screen"/>
```

That's why, `world -> turtle1` transform would be printed by the `turtle1_tf_brodcaster` node.

`world -> turtle2` transform is not being being published on the tf tree at the moment. You can run another instance of `turtlesim_node` so that `world -> turtle2` transform starts getting published. Once you do that, `turtle2_tf_brodcaster` node would be able to print the same.

Does that make sense?

---

Originally posted by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) with karma: 310 on 2021-05-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chan](https://answers.ros.org/users/56593/chan/) on 2021-05-12**:
Great explanation. I tried another one. I removed one instance and kept that param name as turtle2. When I viewed the tf tree, there is no tf data published. Only if I keep the param name as turtle1, it's working. Why is that happening?

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-05-12**:
`<node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node" name="sim"/>`  is responsible for generating the `world -> turtle1`  transform.

If you run `turtle_tf_brodcaster` node with the `turtle` `param` set to `turtle2`, it won't work because it would try to find the transform between `world -> turtle2` and then publish it. But, the `turtlesim_node` is publishing `world -> turtle1` transform on the `tf` tree.

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-05-12**:
Delete everything from the `launch` file and just keep this -

```
<node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node" name="sim"/>
<node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtle_teleop_key" name="teleop" output="screen"/>
```

Now, visualise the `tf` tree.

**Comment by [Chan](https://answers.ros.org/users/56593/chan/) on 2021-05-12**:
Oh cool. Still I don't understand few things. If turtlesim is publishing the world to turtle1 transform, what is the broadcaster code given in the tutorial used for? Isn't it the reason to publish a transform? Am I confusing myself?

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-05-12**:
Could you please attach the `tf` tree you see when you just keep this in your `launch` file -

```
<node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtlesim_node" name="sim"/>
<node pkg="turtlesim" type="turtle_teleop_key" name="teleop" output="screen"/>
```

**Comment by [Chan](https://answers.ros.org/users/56593/chan/) on 2021-05-12**:
Sorry for the late reply. I'm getting as "no tf data received" for those two lines.

**Comment by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) on 2021-05-12**:
`turtlesim_node` only publishes the [turtle's pose](https://docs.ros.org/en/api/turtlesim/html/msg/Pose.html) to a topic--not an actual [transform](https://docs.ros.org/en/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/TransformStamped.html).  When you run the launch file, `turtlesim_node` spawns one turtle automatically (use the [`spawn` service](https://wiki.ros.org/turtlesim#Services) to make more) and publishes the pose for `turtle1` (default name in the [source code](https://github.com/ros/ros_tutorials/blob/74cc182dce2bb7d221052d1d45fe4ad0e7705843/turtlesim/src/turtle_frame.cpp#L114)) on the `/turtle1/pose` topic.  The `turtle1_tf_broadcaster` node subscribes to that topic, gets the pose, and publishes the corresponding transform to the tf tree.

Until you spawn a second turtle, `turtlesim_node` doesn't publish on the `/turtle2/pose` topic, so the second broadcaster won't get a pose and won't publish the transform for `turtle2`.  Therefore, the transform won't exist in the tf tree.

**Comment by [Chan](https://answers.ros.org/users/56593/chan/) on 2021-05-13**:
That explains all. Thanks a lot both..!

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2021-05-13**:
@tryan makes sense. I will update the original answer to reflect this.